# Setting "visible" property of command button on a "navigation control" subform?

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image]

I have been struggling to set the "visible" property of the "owner" button by clicking the "hide owner button. Both are on a subform called "frmSettings" which is on a a tab control which is on a navigation form. I tried all possible combinations of

```
[forms]![frmNavigationForm]![frmSubNavigationForm]![frmSettings].cmdOwner.visible = false
```

without success.

frmSettings is the name of the sub form on which the two buttons are.
cmdOwner is the name of the "Owner" button
tabSettings is the name of the tab control page on which the subform is.

Comment: Actually, I'm using the "hide owner button" only for test purposes. What I really want is to use the line above from within another form (called "frmLogin") the idea is to hide the "owner" button when the user doesn't have permission to use it.

Comment: Run-time error '2465'
can't find the field 'cmdOwner' referred to in your expression

Comment: This is the order of my forms
[frmNavigationForm]![frmSubNavigationForm]![frmSettings].cmdOwner

Comment: Reference container control and `Form` class, not the form it contains. `Forms.[frmNavigationForm].[frmSubNavigationForm].Form.cmdOwner.Visible`

Comment: DO NOT replace `.Form` with `.[frmSettings]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is telling me that "Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)"

Comment: I think I found the problem. I can't hide the button unless the form on which the button is is open !
Can this issue be resolved please?

Comment: Of course form must be open. How could it not be open? Why would user have option to hide Owner button? Why would they even want to bother hiding?

Comment: I want to hide options that allow users to modify the database by hiding the "owner" button which opens settings that allow that.

Comment: But hide options by pressing another button? And user presses that button? Not making sense.